# How can I read MYSQL Database from Android?

Tags: java, php, android, json

I want to read a data from MYSQL database via PHP, JSON from Android.
I've been trying many different examples, but my Android phone wasn't able to read any data.
When I run the application my phone doesn't do anything after loading the application :(

- MYSQL db info

Data Base Name : PeopleData
Table Name : people
Table has : id, name, sex, birthyear

- PHP source : I tested index.php, and the result was correct.

-index.php

```
  <?php
  mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
  mysql_select_db("PeopleData");

  $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE birthyear>1980");
  while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[]=$e;
  print(json_encode($output));
  mysql_close();
  ?>
```

- Android java file for fetching database

  ```
    package com.json;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class JSON extends Activity {

     TextView resultView;
     HttpClient client;
     JSONObject json;

     // the year data to send
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.json);

        resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvjson);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        new Read().execute("text");
     }

     public JSONObject RedData() throws ClientProtocolException,IOException,JSONException {

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/series/database/index.php");     
        HttpResponse r = client.execute(httppost);

        int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (status == 200) {

            HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
            JSONObject last = jArray.getJSONObject(0); // 0 -> the last object
            return last;

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(JSON.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                json = RedData();

                return json.getString(arg0[0]);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            resultView.setText(data);
        }
      }

    }
  ```
- xml

  ```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvjson"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TextView>
  ```
- manifest

  ```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".JSON"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
  ```
- Console

```
    [2012-02-22 16:19:58 - json] Android Launch!
    [2012-02-22 16:19:58 - json] adb is running normally.
    [2012-02-22 16:19:58 - json] Performing com.json.JSON activity launch
    [2012-02-22 16:19:58 - json] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
    [2012-02-22 16:19:59 - json] Uploading json.apk onto device '01499EF80D00D009'
    [2012-02-22 16:19:59 - json] Installing json.apk...
    [2012-02-22 16:20:01 - json] Success!
    [2012-02-22 16:20:01 - json] Starting activity com.json.JSON on device 01499EF80D00D009
    [2012-02-22 16:20:02 - json] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.json/.JSON }
```

- device

  `doing nothing`

I don't know what I can do anymore. Please anybody help me.
Thank you.

Comment: The IP address `127.0.0.1` refers to the local device, so for one the HTTP request is not leaving the device/emulator.

Comment: This is usually a very bad idea security-wise, as there is no protection between Android and your mySQL database, and you have to expose the access credentials to the mobile device. You would usually want to have some sort of API layer in between the client and the database

Comment: Like Pekka said, the best/secure way to communicate with a mysql database from Android is to build an api. Meaning: Create a web app/api that controls talking to the database (with getters and setters, or whatever you need) and then from Android communicate to the database through your web api.

Comment: Thank you for all of the replyes. I tryed with IP Address 10.0.2.2, but it was same. :( I'm a beginner, so I'm not familier with API things. I'm sorry but can I ask website for useful examples or tutorials? Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
package com.Online.Test;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OnlineTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView resultView;
    HttpClient client;
    JSONObject json;
    String Dat;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvjson);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            json = RedData();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      Dat = json.toString();

        new Read().onPostExecute(Dat);
    }
    public JSONObject RedData() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("//link.php");     
        HttpResponse r = client.execute(httppost);

       // int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        //if (status == 200) {

            HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
            JSONObject last = jArray.getJSONObject(0); // 0 -> the last object
            return last;

       // } else {
         //   Toast.makeText(OnlineTestActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          //  return null;
        //}
    }


    public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                json = RedData();
                //Toast.makeText(OnlineTestActivity.this, json.getString(arg0[0]), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                return json.getString(arg0[0]);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            resultView.setText(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be even better if you explained the code and/or corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the points

- The IP address 127.0.0.1 refers to the local device, so for one the
  HTTP request is not leaving the device/emulator.
- At your Server Side Script (here PHP), set
  header('content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
- At doInBackground's Try block, check whether your ReadData() null or
  not.
- At JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data); check whether jArray null
  or not

The following tutorials may help you

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php
- http://appinventor.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-mysql-connectivity-via-json.html
- [Cannot parse JSON data from MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970450/cannot-parse-json-data-from-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your computer is tethered in the same network as your phone.
2. replace 127.0.0.1 with the ipaddress of your computer,, to get the ip address of your computer, perform a :
   "ipconfig" in windows cmd as admin or "ifconfig" on linux, idk for mac
3. then run your app, this should worj....if still you dont get any data, replace your code, and specifically here:
   Dont use JSONArray, instead pass all the data from EnyityUtils to a String and later to a JSONObject without passing via a JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your computer is tethered in the same network as your phone.
2. replace 127.0.0.1 with the ipaddress of your computer,, to get the ip address of your computer, perform a :
   "ipconfig" in windows cmd as admin or "ifconfig" on linux, idk for mac
3. then run your app, this should worry you..if still you dont get any data, replace your code, and specifically here:
   Dont use JSONArray, instead pass all the data from EnyityUtils to a String and later to a JSONObject without passing via a JSONArray