# Cannot parse JSON data from MySQL Database

Tags: android, mysql, json, getjson

I am developing an android application that requires me to connect to a mysql database and retrieve information from it. I am using a php script to connect to the server and query it and then output the results in json format:

```
if(!mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass) || !mysql_select_db($mysql_db)){
die($conn_error);
}



$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM food");

  while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))

          $output[]=$e;

       print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();




?>
```

Here is my java code that uses HttpGet to get the data and convert it to a string. It is then meant to parse the data and show it on the screen.

```
public class HttpExample extends Activity {

TextView httpStuff;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.httpex);
    httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);

    GetMethodEx test = new GetMethodEx();
    String returned;
    try {
        returned = test.getInternetData();
        httpStuff.setText(returned);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public class GetMethodEx {

    public String getInternetData() throws Exception {

        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = "";
        String returnString = null;

        // httpGet

        try {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI website = new URI("http://10.0.2.2/connect.php");
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(website);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                    .getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");

            while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(l + nl);
            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            // return data;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // parse json data
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("log_tag", "Foodname: " + json_data.getString("food"));
                // Get an output to the screen
                returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return returnString;

    }

}

}
```

It is doing everything I want except to parse the data. It is just showing the entire contents of the database on the screen when I only want the food names.Can anyone help?Thanks

edit: Here is a screenshot of my json output from my php script

[image]

Comment: Could you include a sample of the JSON produced by the PHP script?

Comment: Can you copy/paste the JSON? That screenshot is very small and difficult to read.

Comment: [{"id":"1","food":"pizza","calories":"1000","healthy_unhealthy":"u"},{"id":"2","food":"Salad","calories":"300","healthy_unhealthy":"h"}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
returnString += "Foodname: " + json_data.getString("food") + "\n";
```

Instead of

```
returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

I think this will only show foods name. I cant test it right now, because im writing this on my mobile phone.